# Is there is a specific capability to read a serial port?

Tags: linux, serial-port, capability

I want to read data from a GPS attached to an USB and seen by the system as a serial device. I would like not to use `chmod u+s` nor `sudo` and give to the process just the minimum capabilities to do that.

To test, I used the `cat` command:

```
sudo cat /dev/ttyACM0
```

This works, but could I give to `cat` a specific capability to read the serial port?

I tried `setcap cap_sys_rawio+p` and `cap_sys_tty_config+p` without success.
My idea is to give the binary just the minimum rights it need to do its task.

Comment: Nothing special is needed, use chown/chgrp/chmod on the dev file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally ttys belong to a group called something similar to `dialup`.  This is used mainly for old `cu` programs.

One thing you can use (and I do) is to include yourself in the `dialup` group, as you'll see that unused ttys have write permission to owner and group they belong to.

Don't forget to logout and relogon when you test this, as to get the group id for the `dialup` group in the list of groups you belong to requires to pass through the `login(1)` program.

## NOTE

On my system (a FreeBSD 11.x) the gps belongs to group `operator`, and I (my account) belongs to that group.  I can open the gps (bluetooth device with pseudo terminal over a pseudotty)

In  linux, I use `/dev/rfcomm0` (bluetooth) serial device. In debian, `/dev/ttyS0[0-3]` belong to the `dialout` group.  You can use that group.

Comment: I have seen that in Ubuntu the group is dialout. Because I want to give to my process just the minimum possible privileges I solved the problem using ACL and  the command sudo setfacl -m u:processaccount:rw /dev/ttyACM0 where processaccount is the user that is running the process. This is quite the opposite to give to the process a certain capability but I have not found anything better yet.